# Extracting X Y coordinates in projected SR

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, extract

I'm trying to extract X and Y coordinates of a set of points using QGIS 3.20. I am using the "add attributes to geometry tool". Points are in WGS84/33N EPSG:32633 which has Projected bounds:166021.44 0.00 and 534994.66 9329005.18 while WGS84 bounds: 12.0 0.0 18.0 84.0

When I run the tool, it extracts the coordinates always in WGS, but I want them in the projected form.

Does anyone know how to force this?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question directly, but if you use the `Add X/Y fields to layer` tool, you can choose any CRS for the output.

Comment: @Matt thanks for the comment, I tried even with that tool (also Add attributes tool let me select the CRS) but I still get the coordinates in  WGS84 (12.XXX, 18.xxx) instead of UTM33N.. THe whole project CRS is 32633, layer CRS is 32633 and I'm selecting the same CRS when using the tools.. same result =/ I get it that those coordinates are correct, but they are not in the most logical form for that projection..

Comment: If your layer is 32633 you can add a field for the east another for the north. To calculate the East coordinate you can use $X and for the north $Y. This will calculate the coordinate of each point

Answer (score 1):

That is strange. I just tested the tool in one of my data sets in ETRS90 / UTM33N (EPSG:25833) and it seems to work as it should. To check that things are as you expect, select your point data set and run the following script in the python console (under the Plugins menu) This script will also give you the data in a file output.csv in your working directory.

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
with open ('output.csv','w') as outfile:
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        point = feature.geometry().asPoint()
        # Uncomment and add as needed if you want some of the attribute values as well
        # name = feature['name']
        x = point.x()
        y = point.y()
        print(x,y)
        quiet = outfile.write(f"{x},{y}\n")
        # Delete or comment previous line, edit as needed and uncomment 
        # the following line to print attribute values:
        # quiet = outfile.write(f"{x},{y},{name}\n")
```

(the outfile.write will return the number of characters written, the quiet= is just to avoid having that printed to the terminal)

Comment: Thank you very much for the script, I will test it asap. Usually the tool worked for me aswell, but it just stopped giving me the coordinates in the selected CRS at some point..
Will report back if it works! Thanks again!